# Enlarged window buttons after updating to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

After upgrading to Windows 8.1, my window buttons look stretched and enlarged (but they still work). Also, right-clicking on a window from the taskbar has a messed up UI.

[image: http://i.snag.gy/NZKuG.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPpL3.jpg]

What gives. Is there a way to fix it that does not involve reinstalling the OS?

Comment: reinstalling your os won't fix this issue.

Comment: Really? Why is that?

Comment: Because this is a display issue.  System files are not corrupt.

Comment: do you use a 3rd party theme? if yes, use the original Windows 8.1 themes

Comment: Have you ensured your video adapter drivers are running the latest (Win 8.1) version available?

Comment: Oh yes, it was indeed a 3rd party theme. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this picture

[image]

this looks like a 3rd party theme issue. Use the included Windows 8.1 Theme to fix the issue.